# Сохранить выбранные координаты яндекс карты в localstorage

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

при клике на название метки перехожу по ссылке и после перехода  нужно отобразить присвоенные ей координаты. Как сделать чтобы при переходе на страницу показывались нужные координаты, попытался через localstorage [пример](http://tests.roool.ru/temp/map/object_manager.html)

Возможно нужно использовать stringify, но как применить к текущему json не знаю

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map(
      "map",
      {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 10,
      },
      {
        searchControlProvider: "yandex#search",
      }
    ),
    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
      // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
      clusterize: true,
      // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
      gridSize: 32,
      clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
    });

  // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
  // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
  objectManager.objects.options.set({
    iconLayout: "default#image",
    // Своё изображение иконки метки.
    iconImageHref:
      "map_marker_new.png",
    // Размеры метки.
    iconImageSize: [30, 42],
    iconImageOffset: [-3, -42],
  });

  objectManager.clusters.options.set({
    clusterIcons: [
      {
          href: 'claster.svg',
          size: [46, 46],
          offset: [-23, -23]
      }],
    hasBalloon: false,
    groupByCoordinates: false,
    clusterDisableClickZoom: false,
    clusterHideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
    clusterOpenBalloonOnClick: false,
    geoObjectHideIconOnBalloonOpen: false
});
  myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

  $.ajax({
    url: "data-t.json",
  }).done(function (data) {
      
    objectManager.add(data);
  });

  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("[data-objectid]"), function (el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function () {
      let objectid = el.getAttribute("data-objectid");
      window.location.assign(el.getAttribute('data-url'));
      viewObject(objectid);
      console.log(objectid);
    });
  });

  function viewObject(objectid) {
    // Удаляем со всего списка класс active затем добавляем к быранному
    // for (var object of document.querySelectorAll("[data-objectid]")) {
    //   object.classList.remove("active");
    // }
    // document
    //   .querySelector('[data-objectid="' + objectid + '"]')
    //   .classList.add("active");

    let karl = objectManager.objects.getById(objectid).geometry.coordinates;
    localStorage.setItem('myKey', karl);
    let saveCoord = localStorage.getItem('myKey');
    // Центруем по метке
    console.log('Координаты объекта: ' + saveCoord);
    myMap.setCenter([saveCoord],15, {
        checkZoomRange: true,
      }
    );
  }
}
```

```html
    <div>
        <div class="point" data-url="././object_manager.html" data-objectid="1">метка 1</div>
        <div class="point" data-url="././object_manager.html" data-objectid="2">метка 2</div>
        <div class="point" data-url="././object_manager.html" data-objectid="3">м.етка 3</div>
        <div class="point" data-url="././object_manager.html" data-objectid="4">м.етка 4</div>
        <div class="point" data-url="././object_manager.html" data-objectid="5">м.етка 5</div>
        <div class="point" data-url="././object_manager.html" data-objectid="6">м.етка 6</div>
        <div class="point" data-url="././object_manager.html" data-objectid="7">м.етка 7</div>
        <div class="point" data-url="././object_manager.html" data-objectid="8">м.етка 8</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно сохранить метку целиком, то действительно нужно применить stringify:

```
  localStorage.setItem('myKey', JSON.stringify(karl));
  const bgColor = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myKey'));
```

Вызов нужной метки при старте при этом нужно будет добавить после заполнения менеджера объектов данными:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "data-t.json",
  }).done(function (data) {
    objectManager.add(data);
    
    if (localStorage.getItem('myKey')) {
    var startEl = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myKey'))
    viewObject(startEl.id)
    }
  });
```

Comment: переписал вопрос, должно быть понятнее

Comment: Исправил ответ в соответствии с вопросом.

Comment: Большое спасибо, то что надо!